# Bind data from async method

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, async-await

I am still fighting with my project and I need little help to move towards.
In [MainViewModel](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs) I call [Refresh](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs#L94) method to bind data from XML to ObservableCollection.

```
private async Task Refresh()
    {
        var listOfBadges = (await _badgeService.GetAll());
        var listOfSets = (await _setService.GetAll());

        BadgesList.Clear();
        SetsList.Clear();

        BadgesList = listOfBadges.ToObservableCollection<Badge>();

        SetsList = listOfSets.ToObservableCollection<Set>();
    }
```

That is OK ;) In [QuestionViewModel](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/ViewModel/QuestionViewModel.cs) I am editing these data using this method from BadgeService which implement Repository Pattern.

```
public async Task Update(int id)
    {
        StorageFolder sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Data");
        StorageFile st = await sf.GetFileAsync("Badgess.xml");

        var xmlStream = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(st);

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(st);

        using (var stream = await st.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            IXmlNode xee = root.SelectSingleNode("//badge/id[.='" + id + "']");
            xee.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText = "true";
        }

        var xmlStreamUp = xmlDoc.GetXml();

        if (xmlDoc != null)
            await xmlDoc.SaveToFileAsync(st);
    }
```

Data has changes but when I go back to MainViewModel I am not able to see changes after binding, but when I hit [Refresh](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs#L94) method called by button which bind [Command](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs#L153), data after changes are loaded and everything is OK. 
How to avoid hitting Refresh after going back to MainViewModel to properly bind data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176349/assigning-an-async-result-to-a-data-binding-property is similar

Comment: I have to wonder why you're manually manipulating the xml and not using an object and periodically saving it into an xml file. Is the xml acting like some kind of database?

Comment: @Romoku Yes it is kind of database, I use XmlDocument because I get to know that this is good practice in Windows Store apps, I didn't find using Linq2XML example in Windows Store apps.

Comment: Mml isn't very friendly for databases. Have you considered using sqlite? If you're married to xml then try keeping the objects in memory instead of manipulating the xml raw. This will be less error prone and it'll make easier to change the xml format.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on [sqlite for windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263243.aspx) if you're interested.

Comment: @Romoku I thought about sqlite but I am going to end this project based on XML, there will not be much actions on them so they should work. In memory that is interesting, have to read about it

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis it is does not work either, I saw this post before I posted this question

Comment: What I mean by in memory is keep your data as objects in memory and serialize them to xml periodically for durability. That way you don't need to manipulate the xml files except loading them when the app starts and saving them when the app suspends or closes.

Comment: If your database ends up consuming too much memory then you should reconsider using xml. See [How to use XML as a database in windows phone 7 application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4373803/580951).

Comment: @Romoku I realized about pros using them like you say, but I need to solve my problem, your approach maybe is better but is another case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the answer the problem was with calling DialogService to show a popup window, update the xml and go back to the MainViewModel

```
DialogService.ShowMessage("You should try another questions set!", "Game Over!", "Main Menu", GoToMainMenu);
```

it was not awaitable so I had change it to:

```
await DialogService.ShowMessage("You should try another questions set!", "Game Over!");
await GoToMainMenu();
```

And call the Update() method from [BadgeService](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Win8/Services/XML/BadgeService.cs) in awaitable way, like this:

```
private async Task GoToMainMenu()
    {
        await _badgeService.Update(SelectedSet.Id);
        ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
        _navigationService.Navigate("MainPage");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your application is using xml as a backing store consider keeping the objects in memory:

Repository to hold data:

```
public interface IBadgeRepository
{
    // Save Xml File
    Task Save(IEnumerable<Badge> badges);
    // Load Xml File
    Task<Badge> GetAll();
}
```

Service to manipulate data:

```
public sealed class BadgeService : IBadgeService
{
    private readonly IBadgeRepository _badgeRepository;
    private readonly List<Badge> _badges = new List<Badge>();

    public BadgeService(IBadgeRepository badgeRepository)
    {
        _badgeRepository = badgeRepository;
    }

    public async Task<IList<Badge>> GetAll()
    {
        if(!_badges.Any())
        {
            var badges = _badgeRepository.GetAll();
            _badges.AddRange(badges);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(_badge);
    }

    public async Task Update(Badge badge)
    {
        if(!_badges.Contains(badge))
        {
            _badges.Add(badge);
        }
        else
        {
            var index = _badges.IndexOf(badge);
            _badges[index] = badge;
        }

        _badgeRepository.Save(_badges);
    }
}
```

Comment: Big thanks, I will try your approach as you say it is better, but the answer for this question is below.